# Dapper.Query<KeyValueType<T1,T2>> Return a collection of Nulls

Tags: c#, dictionary, generics, dapper

**Simple Issue** (EDITED: To show easy reproducible example first, then the detailed scenario)

Having the following Classes:

```cs
public class SalesMetrics {
   public decimal SalesDollars { get; set; }
   public decimal SalesUnits { get; set; }
}

public class ProductGroup {
   public string ProductId { get; set; }
   public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

using the Following Dapper Query, my result equals `[{Key = null, Value = null}]`:

```cs
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<ProductGroup, SalesMetrics>> result = sqlConnection
   .Query<KeyValuePair<ProductGroup, SalesMetrics>>(
       sql: @"SELECT 
                  1 As ProductId,
                  'Test' AS ProductName, 
                  1.00 As SalesDollars, 
                  1 As SalesUnits");
```

I'm wondering If Dapper could handle a KeyValuePair as output type, is so : how the query need to be?

---

**Full Scenario** (Why I'm needing this)

I am creating a Sales Query builder function that can group my sales results by different grouping predicate and should return different result type based on that predicate `type`.

I am using `Dapper` nuget package to get my result from `SQL-Server`.I am using `Dapper.Query<T>()` extension method on IDbConnection

Basically, no matter the grouping type I want to return a `sum` of SalesDollars & SalesUnits. For this part of the output, I've created the following class `SalesMetrics`

I want my Sales Query function to accept the Group class (`ProductGroup`, or any other class ...) as `generic parameter` named `TGroup`, The function should return a Collection of `KeyValuePair<TGroup,SalesMetric>`

**Data Source**

Here is the layout of my sales Table `FlatSales`

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.FlatSales (
   SalesDate DATE NOT NULL,
   ProductId INT NOT NULL,
   ProductName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   ProductCategoryId INT NOT NULL,
   ProductCategoryName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   CustomerGroupId INT NOT NULL,
   CustomerGroupName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   CustomerId INT NOT NULL,
   CustomerName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   SalesUnits INT NOT NULL,
   SalesDollars INT NOT NULL
)
```

**Where I'm having an Issue**

I have the following function for querying the DB.

```cs
public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TGroup,SalesMetrics>> SalesTotalsCompute<TGroup>(System.Data.IDbConnection connection)
{
    string[] groupByColumnNames = typeof(TGroup)
        .GetProperties(bindingAttr: System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
        .Select(x => x.Name)
        .ToArray();
    string joinedGroupByColumnsNames = string.Join(",", groupByColumnNames);

    return connection.Query<KeyValuePair<TGroup, SalesMetrics>>(sql: $@"
        SELECT SUM(SalesDollars) AS SalesDollars,
            SUM(SalesUnits) AS SalesUnits,
            {joinedGroupByColumnsNames}
        FROM dbo.FlatSales
        GROUP BY {joinedGroupByColumnsNames}
    ");
}
```

**Collection Of NULL**

The code `does not fail` but it return a list of KeyValuePair that both Key and Value are `NULL`.

I've tried to Alias my columns like `ProductName as [Key.ProductName]` but then It does not change anything (Not failing also) ...

Generated Sql queries for `ProductGroup` are as follow (both returns empty KeyValuePair):

```sql
        SELECT SUM(SalesDollars) AS SalesDollars,
            SUM(SalesUnits) AS SalesUnits,
            ProductId,ProductName
        FROM dbo.FlatSales
        GROUP BY ProductId,ProductName

OR
        SELECT SUM(SalesDollars) AS SalesDollars as [Value.SalesDollars],
            SUM(SalesUnits) AS SalesUnits as [Value.SalesUnits],
            ProductId As [Key.ProductId],ProductName As [Key.ProductName]
        FROM dbo.FlatSales
        GROUP BY ProductId,ProductName
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt Dapper supports complex objects like that out-of-the-box.

Perhaps you can benefit from Dapper's [multi-mapping feature](https://dapper-tutorial.net/result-multi-mapping):

```
public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TGroup, SalesMetrics>> SalesTotalsCompute<TGroup>(System.Data.IDbConnection connection)
{
    string joinedGroupByColumnsNames = string.Join(",", GetCachedColumnNamesFor<TGroup>());

    return connection.Query<TGroup, SalesMetrics, KeyValuePair<TGroup, SalesMetrics>>(
        sql: $@"SELECT {joinedGroupByColumnsNames},
                       SUM(SalesDollars) AS SalesDollars,
                       SUM(SalesUnits) AS SalesUnits
                  FROM dbo.FlatSales
              GROUP BY {joinedGroupByColumnsNames}",
        map: (groupData, salesMetricsData) => new KeyValuePair<TGroup, SalesMetrics>(groupData, salesMetricsData),
        splitOn: "SalesDollars");
}
```

**Remarks**

- I've reordered the columns, because splitOn needs the name of the column where the two objects split up, otherwise you'd have to pass the first item from the `joinedGroupByColumnsNames`-array which is a bit more random
- If you're on .NET Standard, consider returning [`ValueTuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=netcore-3.0)'s instead of `KeyValuePair`'s
- Don't use reflection for every call, I suggest to add a method `GetCachedColumnNamesFor` that does the reflection only once, using a static ConcurrentDictionary, calling the [`ConcurrentDictionary.GetOrAdd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.getoradd?view=netcore-3.0) method.

**Other approach**

You could also let `ProductGroup` inherit from `SalesMetrics` (or make an `ISalesMetrics` interface and let `ProductGroup` implement that interface) and do `Query<ProductGroup>(...)`. An additional benefit would be that duplicate fields in both models would be blocked by the compiler.

The resulting method would then look like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSalesData> SalesTotalsCompute<TSalesData>(System.Data.IDbConnection connection)
    where TSalesData : ISalesMetric
{
    string joinedGroupByColumnsNames = string.Join(",", GetCachedNonSalesMetricColumnNamesFor<TSalesData>());

    return connection.Query<TSalesData>(sql: $@"
        SELECT SUM(SalesDollars) AS SalesDollars,
            SUM(SalesUnits) AS SalesUnits,
            {joinedGroupByColumnsNames}
        FROM dbo.FlatSales
        GROUP BY {joinedGroupByColumnsNames}
    ");
}
```

Here the `GetCachedNonSalesMetricColumnNamesFor`-method reflects the properties from `TSalesData` excluding those from the `ISalesMetric` interface, again, caching the result.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion,  I've already thought about it but I have +/- 20 `grouping classes` and I use them not only to get `SalesMetrics` but for other measures (Eg: `ForecastMetrics, Inventory, Calls ...`) I want to reduce the amount of code/classes as much as possible. Maybe there are other approaches than KeyValuePair.. I'm searching

Comment: `Multi-mapping-feature`! That's what I was looking for! Thank you so much! Thanks about pointing for the ConcurentDictionary & Tupples. Your edit might have missed the `GetCachedNonSalesMetricColumnNamesFor` function, I already have a concurent caching mecanism in my application, I'll reuse that for caching the full sql query text by KeyType & ValueType!

Comment: Left it out intentionally as I'm leaving the implementation up to you :) (unless you're stuck). It's especially a good idea to cache type reflections like this because they can be slow and you only want to do them once for each type.